# Does nutrition information for unshelled edamame include or exclude the shell?

Tags: nutrition, soy

I am wondering whether the [nutrition information](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/generic-edamame-unshelled-in-pods-569941496) for unshelled [edamame](https://www.thespruce.com/what-is-edamame-3376830) - young soy beans - include the nutritional values for the shell or not.

Answer (score 1):

The nutritional value of the shell is included.

I came to this conclusion by comparing the macronutrient ratios of shelled vs. unshelled edamame and found that shelled edamame delivered a higher portion of energy from protein and fat, and a lower portion from carbs. This is consistent with knowledge that more of the protein and fat is concentrated into the soy bean, whereas the shells are more fibrous.

The difference is significant (-18% carbs, +40% fat, +22% protein) so if you're tracking nutrient intake exactly, you'll want to pick the food item that matches whether or not you're eating the shell.